# javascript remove last occurrence on a given string

Tags: javascript

How to convert the following using js regex replace or something:

```
var text = "line1<br>line2<br>line3<br>line4<br>"
...js regex...
```

so that text becomes:

```
text = "line1<br>line2<br>line3<br>";
```

of course the number of br varies, and each line length varies too

Comment: You want to remove the fourth line? I don't understand. Also, I doubt regex is the proper tool for this.

Comment: Use `.split()` to split it into an array, delete the last element of the array, then `.join()` to combine them back into a string.

Answer (score 1):

Removing just the last line without regular expressions:

```
var text = "line1<br>line2<br>line3<br>line4<br>";
var pieces = text.split('<br>');
var newText = pieces.splice(0, pieces.length-2).join('<br>') + '<br>';
```

Note that this code makes at least three important assumptions:

1. The separator is always `<br>` and not, say, `<br />` or `<BR>`.
2. The input string always ends with a `<br>`.
3. The result string always ends with `<br>`, even if it's otherwise empty! (For example, if the input string is `line1<br>` then the output will be `<br>`.

Comment: For `line1<br>`, it returns `<br>`. Whether or not that is correct is a matter of the requirements, I suppose.

Comment: Also, to avoid the issue number 1 in your list, i'll rather use the following regex in your split:   `/<br\s?\/?>/i` http://jsfiddle.net/gx0x4m40/

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that I am posing just because I took the time to make it. It works but needs index and null checks and such.

```
var text = "line1<br>line2<br>line3<br>line4<br>";
var newText = text.substring(0, text.substring(0, text.length - 4).lastIndexOf("<br>"));
```

Comment: why is minus 4 there ?

Comment: It will eliminate the <br> text from the end. That way the lastIndexOf function will get the location of the second to last <br> tag.